# CallKit and PushKit delegate methods are not being called in iOS 14

Tags: voip, ios14, callkit, pushkit

VoIP calls are not being connected in iOS 14. Please help if anyone faced similar issue.

Comment: In general CallKit and PushKit work properly on iOS 14. Unless you provide us more info and some code of your app, it's impossible to guess what's your issue.

Comment: @Marco Same code works in iOS 13, so wanted to check if there is something new for iOS 14.